# Why does mutating a list-column with a single-element list result in a deep copy?

Tags: r, deep-copy, dplyr, tibble

I was unaware that creating a new list-column with `dplyr::mutate()` with a single-element list actually deep-copies the element to fill the tibble length (see `t3`). Why is that?

If I specify the correct length explicitly (`t4`) or pass it when creating the tibble (`t5`), the elements are passed by reference.

Consider the following case, where a list encloses a tibble with a large vector.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pryr)

t1 <- tibble(a = 1:4)
t2 <- tibble(b = 1:1e6)
t3 <- mutate(t1, tl = list(t2))
t4 <- mutate(t1, tl = rep(list(t2), n()))
t5 <- tibble(a = 1:4, tl = list(t2))

object_size(t2)
#> 4 MB
object_size(t3)
#> 16 MB
object_size(t4)
#> 4 MB
object_size(t5)
#> 4 MB
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>